# TMG 2010 Physical to Virtual conversion using Vmwar Vcenter standalone converter

Tags: windows, vmware-esxi, conversion, tmg

I converted Physical TMG 2010 R2 SP2 machine (Windows 2008 R2 SP1) to VM by using VMware Vcenter Standalone converter but stucked in following situation after successful conversion.

1) No adapters are available in TMG console (I was using 3 adapters, 1 LAN, 2 WAN (internet))

2) I tried several proposed solutions including deleting all hidden devices, adapters from device manager and change adapters by editing VM settings (intel 1000) but no luck.

3) Microsoft firewall (TMG) service / control service cant start.

4) Network adapters are visible in Network connections with proper IP assigned manually.

Please help me to resolve this issue as i have to move all physical machines to VMWare.

Answer (score 1):

A few things I would look at first would be the following.
1. All proprietary software related to the physical server removed? (HP Branded software for network adapters, etc. Dell, etc)
2. Did you install VMware tools inside the guest OS?
3. Tried VMXnet 3 network adapter?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue converting my virtual TMG 2010 Hyper-V to VMWare (No adapters are available in TMG console) with Vcenter standalone converter. After several fails I tried running the TMG Wizard and that fix the problem, now I can see the network adapters in TMG.